# how to handle result of graph api to get list of user's groups in Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, object, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my facebook app. I need to get a list of user's group. But Problem is I am not good in JavaScript so unable to handle result. Using graph api I am able to get name of user by using

```
response.name
```

but in group list, it looks different. Script I used to get group List

```
FB.api(
"/me/groups",
function (response) {
if (response && !response.error) {
/* handle the result */
}
}
);
```

But I don't know how to handle. when I try it in graph explorer Result is like

```
{
"data": [
{
"name": "jindagi na melegi dubara", 
"unread": 9, 
"bookmark_order": 999999999, 
"id": "1398847113716538"
}, 
{
"name": "Online IT Clubs", 
"unread": 25, 
"bookmark_order": 999999999, 
"id": "556540827777044"
}, 
{
"name": "Bank exams preparation(2014)", 
"bookmark_order": 9, 
"id": "663444460375219"
 }, 
 ], 
"paging": {
 "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/802942813062683/groups?   icon_size=16&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=enc_AeyYqXtvk-KAYVvplkod74WiEHqLL6BfmTfuR5gchidafW3rWME4kpqm5YdHLPYkVw0o93poJ7Ib41eOoitEi-Tk"
}
}
```

I want to use group Id and Name in my app. Can you tell me how to handle result. Thanks in advance.

Edit : I also check foloowing edits 
Edit 1

```
FB.api(
"/me/groups",
function (response) {
if (response && !response.error) {
response.data[0].name
}
}
);
```

But No result to display.

Edit 2

```
FB.api(
"/me/groups",
function (response) {
if (response && !response.error) {
for (var l = response.data.length, i = 0; i < l; i++) {
var obj = response.data[i];
console.log(obj.name);
console.log(obj.id);
}
}
}
);
```

Same problem again

Comment: It should be accessed as `response.data[0].name`

Comment: no more working until app is checked by Facebook staff, since april 2018: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/?locale=it_IT

Answer (score 2):

Since the details are inside the `data` attribute which is in array format you should iterate the `response.data` and extract the `name` and other details

Your response structure is

response

```
--data
----[
------{
------name
------unread
------bookmark_order
------id
------}
------{
------....
------}
------]
----paging
------next
```

Code (jQuery)

```
 $.each(response.data, function (i, obj) {
    console.log(obj.name);
    console.log(obj.unread);
    console.log(obj.bookmark_order);
    console.log(obj.id);
 });
```

Code (JS)

```
for (var l = response.data.length, i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    var obj = response.data[i];
    console.log(obj.name);
    console.log(obj.unread);
    console.log(obj.bookmark_order);
    console.log(obj.id);
}
```

Comment: @anandsharma console the `response` and check whether it is same as that you got from graph explorer

Comment: I used 'console.log(response);' but no result

Comment: @anandsharma Then the issue must be in the request you do. You are not getting any response. See why your are having no result

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to display the info. You could use jQuery or some other library to dynamically update a `<div>` elements content for example.

Have a look at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eCy58/1/

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this problem : (before you know the response.fields)

```
FB.api(
"{your rwquest}",
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {

    var {your_Arrey} = [] ;
    response['data'].forEach(function(data) {
    if (data.status != null)
    {your_Arrey}.push(data.{1}+data.{2}+'<br>');});
    console.dir({your_Arrey});

  }
}
```

Remplace {your rwquest},{your Arrey} and {1},{2} with your data.
After your works fine with your Arrey

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.

```js
 FB.api('/me/groups', function(response) {
   var l = response.data.length;
   for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
     var obj = response.data[i];
     var groupName = obj.name;
     var groupId = obj.id;
   }
 });
```